# fatal error when calling wp_create_nonce in options-init.php

Tags: wordpress, boilerplate, redux-framework

I am developing a wordpress plugin using the wordpress boilerplate template. Additionally, I am using Redux Framework as an options framework. I load the options-init.php in the load_dependencies() function of the main include file.

Everything works fine. However, when calling wp_create_nonce in options-init.php I get a Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce()

Why is it and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself, although not sure if it is correct/best practice.

I moved the include of the redux framework into a seperate class which I call via action hook on ''plugins_loaded'

//Initiate Redux Framework
$this->loader->add_action( 'plugins_loaded', $plugin_admin_redux, 'init_redux_framework' );

Inside the method init_redux_framework() I just put the require once to the admin-init.php

Interestingly though that adding it on 'init' instead of 'plugins_loaded' was too late for Redux to be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_create_nonce()` is a pluggable function loaded after plugins are loaded.

Be sure to call your class method on proper hook, `'init'` (or later) is a good place: once your function output something (a form) there is no reason to run earlier than that.

`wp_verify_nonce()` receives 2 arguments:

```
$nonce
$action
```

**1st argument is the nonce, and comes from the request**

In fact, `wp_verify_nonce()` have to be used like so:

```
// here I assume that the form is submitted using 'post' as method
$verify = wp_verify_nonce($_POST['message-send']);
```

So the first argument passed to wp_verify_nonce() is exactly the value that is present in the hidden field

**2nd argument: the `wp_create_nonce()` method**

Regarding the second argument, it depends on how you build the nonce value.

E.g. if you did:

```
<?php $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'custom-action' ); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="message-send" value="<?php echo $nonce ?>" />
```

Then you need to do:

```
$verify = wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['message-send'], 'custom-action' );
```

So, the second argument is what was used as argument to `wp_create_nonce()`.

**2nd argument: the `wp_nonce_field()` method**
If you created the nonce using wp_nonce_field() like:

```
wp_nonce_field( 'another_action', 'message-send' );
```

Then you need to verify the nonce like so:

```
$verify = wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['message-send'], 'another_action' );
```

So, this time, the action is whatever passed as first argument to `wp_nonce_field()`.

**Recap**:
To pass `wp_verify_nonce()` validation you need to pass 2 arguments to the function, one is the value in the nonce hidden field, the other is the action, and depends on how the nonce value was built.

Comment: Are you a bot? Nice copy paste standard post that has absolutely nothing to do with my question. Did you even read my comment? Init or later is too late btw.!

Answer (score 1):

wp_create_nonce() is a pluggable function loaded after plugins are loaded. 
BEFORE call pluggable.php file:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php' );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `wp_create_nonce()` inside plugin?

Nonce is usually included in a hidden HTML form field or as a part of an URL and therefore sent with a request by submitting a form field or visiting a link:

```
<?php
// Create an nonce for a link.
// We pass it as a GET parameter.
// The target page will perform some action based on the 'do_something' parameter.
$nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'my-nonce' );
?>
<a href='myplugin.php?do_something=some_action&_wpnonce=<?php echo $nonce; ?>'>Do some action</a>
```

And inside plugin files you can verify nounce:

```
wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'my-nonce' );
```